# Design substitute to popping up new frames on each click in WxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

My application consists of looking into a live feed from a spectroscope (optical instrument) and extracting frames from it. Clicking a point in the feed launches a **new Frame** where the image is analysed. Each frame handles a **single panel**.

The action of creating  a new frame is very easy for a programmer to do (immediate showing and focus capture, discrete objects, no complex layout management, easy meaning for close button).

I now want a design that works in a single window. What is the easiest design pattern that **replaces** the practice of creating new frames? It should offer the same advantages (see previous paragraph) as far as possible. I am thinking of using tabs to manage the panels as they can capture focus, hide/show panels, destroy themselves elegantly etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would put your feed inside a sizer with space for two elements. Have the feed expand to fill your window unless the second space in the sizer is available. Then, when you click the feed, add a panel with the detailed information to the empty part of the sizer.

You can add a close button which would simply close and remove the panel in the same way as your currently do.

Answer (score 0):

Create a frame with two main elements:

1. Your current feed
2. A navigation control such as a wx.ListBox, wx.ListCtrl, or wx.TreeCtrl to allow you to scroll through and click on the feed you want displayed in element (1).